# Ternary operator with lists

Tags: python, conditional-operator

I have a list of strings in *Python*, in which some of the strings start with character `-`, and I want to remove such character.

I tried this sentence:

```
columns = [column[1:] for column in columns if column.startswith('-') else column]
```

but I get a `Sintax Error` exception.

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the result of the ternary operator to be the thing that goes in the list, so it all goes on the left:

```
columns = [column[1:] if column.startswith('-') else column for column in columns]
```

You can use an `if` *after* the `for .. in ...` to filter items out of the iteration completely, but `else` has no meaning in that context, which is why you got a `SyntaxError`.